# Apache2 conf redirect

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

Looking for what is the best practice for this.

I have 2 domains, `oldsite.com` and `mynewsite.com`

Added these to my `oldsite.com` apache2 config file:

```
#homepage 
Redirect 301 / https://www.mynewsite.org

#rest of pages
Redirect 301 /old/page/location1 https://www.mynewsite.org/some/new/page1
Redirect 301 /old/page/location2 https://www.mynewsite.org/another/new/page/here
```

I have tons of redirects to do though (100+). Like to keep it as neat as possible. Looking for the best practice for this. Say `mynewsite.com` changes some day. I'd like to be able to update just one location in the conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have control over Apache config on old domain.

It is better to use [**`RewriteMap`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for your requirements for thousands of redirection. Here is how you can use it:

1. Add following line to your `httpd.conf` file to define a `RewriteMap`:

   ```
   RewriteMap redirMap txt://full/path/to/redirects.txt
   ```
2. Create a text file as `/full/path/to/redirects.txt` like this:

   ```
   /old/page/location1 /new/pag1
   /old/page/location2 /new/pag2
   / /
   ```
3. Add these line in your apache config or vhost config or site root .htaccess:

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond ${redirMap:$0} .
   RewriteRule .* https://www.mynewsite.org${redirMap:$0} [L,R=301,NE]
   ```

This is pretty handy for `mynewsite.com` changes some day requirement as **you will need to change domain name in one rule only**.

Comment: This works. Thanks! 

One other question, I found I could use:
`RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewsite.org`

But when I use this, all other redirects I set up get sent to the root (homepage). Just curious if there is a way to have this and also have manual redirects work also.

Comment: I suggest keeping all redirects in `redirect.txt` file. However if there is a use case to keep other `301` redirects then keep them **after** this rule. And definitely keep `RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ https://www.mynewsite.org` at the very end since it will match everything.

Comment: Perfect, wanted to confirm that was the case. Thanks again for everything.